# React Native Redux - Not showing updated state via different route

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

I'm writing a react-native app via expo and trying to implement redux. I'm not sure if I'm going about this completely the wrong way. I have a home page that has two sections, a search text box and an area with links to content pages. The content pages also contain the same search box component. I want to be able to pass the contents of the search box input to the content page so that the user doesn't need to enter this again (and will probably require access to this content further in the user journey)

My app.js looks like the below:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import ContentPage from './pages/ContentPage.js';
import LogoTitle from './components/LogoTitle';
import EventsListPage from './pages/EventsListPage.js';
import EventPage from './pages/EventPage';
import VenuePage from './pages/VenuePage';
import HomeScreen from './pages/HomePage';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const initialState ={
  postcode:"abcefg"
}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type)
    {
      case 'SET_POSTCODE':
        return {
            postcode: action.text
        }
        default:
          console.log("returning default state")
          return state
    }
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    ContentPage: ContentPage,
    EventsListPage: EventsListPage,
    EventPage: EventPage,
    VenuePage: VenuePage
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: () => <LogoTitle />,
      headerLeft: () => null,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ADD8E6'
      }
    },
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>);
  }
}
```

Homepage.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import SearchBox from '../components/SearchBox'
import TypeDrillDownArea from '../components/TypeDrillDownArea'
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
    };
  }

   render() {
   
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SearchBox navigation={this.props.navigation} eventTypeId=''/>
        <TypeDrillDownArea navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>

    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen
  

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'stretch'
  
  
    },
  });
```

Relevant searchbox.js:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={topperBackground} style={{width: '100%'}}>
      <View>
          <View style={styles.row}>
              <View>
              <TextInput
            value={this.props.postcode}
            autoCapitalize="characters"
            style={styles.inputBox}
            placeholder="Enter Postcode"
            onChangeText={(e) => this.props.setPostcode(e)}
          />
              </View>
              <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                  disabled={this.state.locationDisabled}
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('EventsListPage', {
                    navigation: this.props.navigation,
                    eventTypeId: this.state.eventTypeId,
                    locLongitude: this.state.location.coords.longitude,
                    locLatitude: this.state.location.coords.latitude,
                    });
                  }}>
                      <Image
                          style={styles.locationPin}
                          source={locationPin}
                      />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.searchButtonArea}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  console.log("postcode is: " + this.state.postcode)
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('EventsListPage', {
                      eventTypeId: this.state.eventTypeId,
                      postcode: this.props.postcode,
                  });
              }}>
                  <Text style={styles.searchButton}>SEARCH</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      </View>
      
      </ImageBackground>);
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBox)


function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    postcode:state.postcode
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    setPostcode : (e) => dispatch({
      type: 'SET_POSTCODE',
      postcode : e
    })
  }
}
```

and finally relevant contentpage.js:

```
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <SearchBox navigation={this.props.navigation} eventTypeId={this.state.eventTypeId} />
          <Image source={imageType(this.state.dataSource[0].eventTypeId)} style={styles.eventType} />
          <Text style={styles.textToDisplay}>
            {this.state.dataSource[0].eventTypeDescription}
          </Text>
        </View>
```

On load, the box is prepopulated with "abcefg" as expected. Changing the contents hits the reducer as expected. However when I navigate to a content page which loads the search box again the value is empty, regardless if I've changed the original state or not.

Am I missusing redux for what it's intended? Should I be doing this a different way?

For clarity below is the organisation of the components

[image: App Tree Diagram]

Comment: In your `reducer()`, you are accessing `action.text` but in your `dispatch()`, you are passing the postcode value to `postcode` key instead of `text`

Comment: @codemax can you put this as an answer because this is what fixed the issue, I cant believe I missed that. Code blindness I guess. This problem has been destroying my soul for days....

Comment: Sure! Glad that helped :) Always good to have a second pair of eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `reducer()`, you are accessing `action.text` but in the `dispatch()`, you passed `postcode` value to `postcode` instead of `text`.